# Object Returned from Function Calls Destructor

Tags: c++, function, object, return, destructor

In `C++`, I have a function which returns a first-class object by value, like this:

```
Image Video::getFrame(int frame) {
    Image img(...);

    ... processing ...

    return img;
}
```

After the value is returned and `img` goes out of scope, the `Image` destructor is called, destroying all of the data inside the object. Therefore, whenever I do this:

```
Image frame = video.getFrame(10);
```

`frame` appears as though it is completely uninitialized.

I thought return by value was supposed to make a complete, separate copy of `img`. Somehow, I misunderstanding what is going on. How can I overcome this problem?

**Note:** None of the member variables within `Image` are pointers.

Comment: How are you determining that `frame` is uninitialized?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I said "appears as though it is completely uninitialized". This is because of a call to `Image::~Image()` after the function `getFrame()` returns.

Comment: A copy did occur, so how are you determining that `frame` was uninitialized?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Examining the data in the Visual Studio debugger shows that all of the data which was in `img` before the return, is absent from `frame` after the return has occurred.

Comment: It seems to me Image is your own class and you need to specify copy constructor. If you will google 'copy constructor' you will find why.

Comment: @Sekory I have built a copy constructor, which does copy the data, but a call to the destructor destroys the copied data.

Comment: @Oliver: How that can be? If you return your object by value then this will happen (assume no move constructor is in play): 1) copy constructor is invoked -> you will create second object. 2) first object is destroyed (that's why destructor is called). But maybe I don't understand you question. Try to add your copy constructor code and what is uninicialized.

Comment: @Sekory According to the debugger the neither the copy constructor nor the overloaded = operator are called. This is what is really perplexing me.

Comment: One more thing, did you try to examine the object outside the debugger? From my experience debuggeres aren't 100% realiable. Although in this case it would be very strange behaviour. And did you move your debugger to the next line? If you are with your debugger on this line 'Image frame = video.getFrame(10);' it is maybe uninicialized yet -> go to the next line...

Comment: @Sekory Unfortunately, I did. All of my tests show that neither the overloaded = operator nor the copy constructor are called. Also `frame` truly contains uninitialized data, as the next line of my code throws an exception because of it.

Comment: 2Oliver: In that case I am not able to help you anymore. The code which you posted seems to be fine to me. So probably there is wrong something else. Try to add more code...

Comment: @Sekory Thank you for your help, but this code is under NDA, so I cannot post anymore. I will just have to keep trying on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out why. A minor discrepancy which turned out to be a big deal. `frame` was of type `Image*` not `Image`. So, it was pointing to the `img` variable inside the function, not copying its data. When the destructor was called, the data at that variable was pointing at was destroyed.

I knew this wasn't making sense...